# Cannot enable mode rewrite

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, xampp, wampserver

I want to use mod_rewrite with Wampserver to remove "/index.php/" from addressbar. This code is suggested with Codeigniter Framework:

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|table-images|robots\.txt|css|fonts|js|uploads|dbg-wizard\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This should change this url:

```
mysite.local/contact_us
```

to this:

```
mysite.local/index.php/contact_us
```

This works with XAMPP but with Wampserver first URL generates Error 404!
I enabled mod_rewrite with Apache and there is no errors in error log.

**Update:**

I added .blabla in .htacess but nothing happened! It means that Apache does not read .htaccess! Why?

---

I added AllowOverride All to httpd-vhosts.conf.
Apache did not execute .htaccess and **enabling AllowOverride in httpd.conf is not enough.**

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<Directory E:\mysite\www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
#Order Deny,Allow   
#Allow from all 
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: did your restart your server ?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer?

Comment: I restarted everytime. My wampserver is : "wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b"

Comment: Check values of directives `AccessFileName` and `AllowOverride`.

Answer (score 0):

To check that mode rewrite is working or not try these steps:

1. Make a folder in your root directory called ***htaccess_test***
2. Create a ***.htaccess*** file, and put these code into this and save it.

   ```
       options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine On        
       RewriteBase /htaccess_test/ 
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
       RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1
   ```
3. Create one more file called ***user.php*** and put these code into
   this and save it.

   ```
   <?php
    if(isset($_GET['u'])){
    echo $_GET['u'];
    }
   ```
4. Now go to browser type http://localhost/htaccess_test/put_some_value_here.

If that is working than the problem is not in your apache setting.
Make sure you are editing the right ***.htaccess*** file. The ***.htaccess*** file you need to edit is in your projects' root folder, not in application or any other folder. And put these code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root_directory_of_your_project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```